mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
mySQL на Windows проработал без проблем более 2 лет. Затем временами стал отключаться, но простая перезагрузка компьютера проблему решала. Но это продолжалось недолго и появилась эта ERROR 1045. Перепробовал все способы, что нашел в Интернете, без успеха. И, наконец, переустановил всю систему с резервной копии. Ошибка не исчезла.

Перепробовал все способы, что нашел в Интернете - огласите, пожалуйста, весь список. чтобы вам могли посоветовать что-то другое, чего вы ещё не пробовали.

Ошибка вполне вменяемо говорит, что выполняется попытка подключиться от имени рута без пароля. А поскольку пароль у рута, скорее всего , имеется, то подключение отвергается.

Убедитесь, что ваш пароль не содержит специальных символов, и просто используйте простой пароль (например: 12345), он будет работать.

Также иногда помогает login:mysql Password:mysql

странный рецепт
